# Monero wallet password - recovery of wallet and XMR

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery, password-confirmation

I'm in trouble. I don't remember my Monero wallet password. And I don't have the private keys or the 25 word seed. Is it possible to get the password? I'm using the GUI wallet. Does the PC not save something that can help? I mean like a file, cache or something?

I have the .keys file, but not the address, secret spend key, secret view key or password to open it.

I have my public address from a transaction I made when i created the wallet. Is it possible to get my Monero back?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your seed or password, you cannot recover your XMR.